# Como generar degrados en texto css3

Tags: html, css, css3

[image]Hola quería saber como generar un degradado en un texto como la imagen adjunta. o si hay algun generador en la web para poder realizarlo

Comment: No has puesto ninguna imagen adjunta. Por otra parte, esta no es la manera en la que se preguntan cosas. De momento aquí tienes la respuesta: http://bfy.tw/FAmb

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Puedes utilizar CSS3 para ello, con un `background` utilizando un `linear-gradient` que, combinado con la propiedad `-webkit-background-clip: text;` y `-webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;` harán el efecto que tu quieres.

Ejemplo:

```css
#degradado{
  background: linear-gradient(yellow, green);
  -webkit-background-clip: text;
  -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
}
```

```html
<h1 id="degradado">ARTIFICIAL</h1>
```

Comment: Muchas gracias Francisco